# How do you catch a buggy sig die handler if the mechanism to debug code that everyone uses overrides it?

Tags: perl, signals, eval, die, carp

Let's say you use a cpan (or otherwise external) module, like our fictional one here `Stupid::CPAN::Module::OfSatan`

```
package Stupid::CPAN::Module::OfSatan {
  BEGIN { $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { print STDERR "ERROR"; exit; }; }
}
```

Now later in your code you have something very innocent,

```
package main {
  eval { die 42 };
}
```

This is going to trigger your buggy signal handler. You're going to want to know where that buggy signal handler is defined, so you'll do something logical like insert a [`Carp::Always`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Always),

```
package main {
  use Carp::Always;
  eval { die 42 };
}
```

`Carp::Always` will then override the buggy signal handler, and your code will magically work. How can you debug where the code is that introduces a buggy signal handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [`Devel::Confess`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Confess)

From `mst` on `irc.freenode.net/#perl`,

```
< mst> EvanCarroll: Devel::Confess honours the old signal handlers
< mst> EvanCarroll: it's basically a better Carp::Always
< EvanCarroll> Cool cool, thanks for that tidbit.
```